# Assigning date variable in Google Big Query query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to add a date variable in my query in GBQ.

So I have variable x (ex: 2016-04-20) which I want to use in query like:

```
    #Query the necessary data
    customer_data_query = """ 
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, Organisation, CustomerRegisterDate FROM `bigquery-bi.ofo.Customers` 
    where CustomerRegisterDate > @max_last_date LIMIT 5) """
    print(customer_data_query)

    # Creating a connection to the google bigquery
    client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('./credentials/cred_ofo.json')
    print("Connection to Google BigQuery is established")
    query_params = [
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("max_last_date", "STRING", max_last_date),
    ]
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    job_config.query_parameters = query_params
    customer_data = client.query(
        customer_data_query,
        # Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
        location="US",
        job_config=job_config,
    ).to_dataframe()  # API request - starts the query
```

Any tips on how I can do it?

I have tried in the code above but not worked.

Comment: did you have chance to read [Running parameterized queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries)? which part does not work for you? please be more specific! Also, check out recently introduced [Scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) and [Stored Procedure](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_procedure) - this might serve your needs even better :o)

Comment: Yeah, I was trying exactly like how it is in documentation. But not happening. @MikhailBerlyant

Comment: where you define value of `max_last_date` in `bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("max_last_date", "STRING", max_last_date)` ? tha's might be what you are missing

Comment: Hello, would you mind posting the fix as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

There were 2 solutions:

1 was to use format:

```
 """SELECT FirstName, LastName, Organisation, CustomerRegisterDate FROM `bigquery-bi.ofo.Customers` where CustomerRegisterDate > {} LIMIT 5""".format(max_date)
```

2:
 To define parameters to be able to use in `job_config`, which is mentioned in BigQuery parametrized query documentation.